# MYSQL slow left join on function calls

Tags: mysql

Here I want to make join on following tables on there tracking_no as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM tracker_mngr AS pkgdsp 
LEFT JOIN tracker AS taq ON taq.tracking_no LIKE CONCAT('%', pkgdsp.tracking_no ,'%')
```

but it takes more time to execute the query,following is the table structure

**Table Structures :**

```
CREATE TABLE `tracker_mngr` (
`id_package_dispatching` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tracking_no` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_package_dispatching`),
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tracker` (
`tracking_no` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`status` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`status_input_date` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`status_input_time` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`tracking_no`,`status`,`status_input_date`,`status_input_time`),
UNIQUE KEY `idx_tracking_no_status_01` (`tracking_no`,`status`,`status_input_date`,`status_input_time`),
KEY `idx_tracking_no_01` (`tracking_no`)
)ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but I dont have privileges to create Index on tracker_mngr table,following is sample of tracking_no in tables
tracker_mngr containts tracking_no as

tracking_no
A113035604231A
A113035604220A-1
113036092514
113036092433-1

and tracker containts tracking_no as

tracking_no
113035604231 for (A113035604231A)
113035604220 for (A113035604220A-1)
113036092514 for (113036092514)
113036092433 for (113036092433-1)

here is Explain command table of my query

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pkgdsp | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 127362 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | taq    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  79766 |       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

but it is taking more time to execute,and I have created index on it but it is not using any index for searching as shown in above table.
so how can I amprove the performance of this query ?

Comment: LIKE is slow... In addition to CONCAT as well.

Comment: You'd need another column with tracking_no, otherwise it's full text search which is of course very slow...

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `column LIKE %column%` definitively defeats the use of indexing. This basically amounts to a full-text search of a column's contents.

If you can eliminate the first `%` sign in your join logic you'll have a chance of running this join quickly.  Otherwise what you see is all you get.

*Edit*  `LIKE` itself isn't slow.  For example `column LIKE 'text%'` can work fine if `column` is indexed.  It's `column LIKE '%text%'` that's necessarily and forever slow.

*Another Edit*  `JOIN ... ON` operations are much faster when they take the form

```
  ON a.col = b.col
```

and both a.col and b.col have indexes.   Join operations like this

```
 ON a.col = somefunction(b.col)
```

cause the DBMS to have to run the function an extremely large number of times.  Your `OR` clause makes it even worse.

The Oracle and PostGreSQL databases offer functional indexes. That is, you can create an index on `somefunction(b.col)` if you want. That will help your join. However, MySQL does not offer that index type.

To get good performance, you're going to need to refactor your data to use

```
 ON taq.tracking_no = pkgdsp.clean_tracking_no
```

That means you're going to have to add a column to pkgdsp and figure out how to populate it with a purified tracking number.  Then you'll create an index on it.

This is your only choice in MySQL. It's also by far the best choice for the integrity of your data.

**Yet another edit. **

This query will yield your first table with the tracking number cleaned up, provided you don't have any tracking numbers in that table that begin with more than one letter.

```
  SELECT id_package_dispatching,
         CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN ASCII(UPPER(tracking_no))>57 
                   THEN SUBSTR(tracking_no,2) 
                   ELSE tracking_no 
                    END AS INT) AS CHAR) AS tracking_no
    FROM tracker_mngr
```

This works because `CAST(... AS INT)` ignores trailing non-integer characters.  We then cast it back to CHAR because we want it to be comparable to the tracking_no in your other table.

You can use this cleaned up virtual table in your LEFT JOIN operation in place of the original `tracker_mngr` table.  You'll still have to scan the whole `tracker_mngr` table, but the ON operation should be lots cheaper.

Like so:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT id_package_dispatching,
               CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN ASCII(UPPER(tracking_no))>57 
                         THEN SUBSTR(tracking_no,2) 
                         ELSE tracking_no 
                          END AS INT) AS CHAR) AS tracking_no
          FROM tracker_mngr
       )AS pkgv
  LEFT JOIN tracker AS taq ON taq.tracking_no = pkgv.tracking_no
```

This is definitely an inferior solution to storing the cleaned-up data in your table, but it should help.

Comment: Agree! Never use `%` as a prefix bcoz mysql don't use index in that case.

Comment: To be precise, I don't think *any* database will use an index in that case - there is just (at least to my knowledge) - no way to do this in any reasonable amount of space and time.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM tracker_mngr AS pkgdsp 
LEFT JOIN tracker AS taq 
ON taq.tracking_no = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(pkgdsp.tracking_no,1, CHAR_LENGTH(pkgdsp.tracking_no) - 1),2)   
OR taq.tracking_no = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(pkgdsp.tracking_no,1, CHAR_LENGTH(pkgdsp.tracking_no) - 3),2) 
OR taq.tracking_no = SUBSTRING(pkgdsp.tracking_no,1, CHAR_LENGTH(pkgdsp.tracking_no) - 2) 
OR taq.tracking_no = pkgdsp.tracking_no

Comment: this query is more slower than above query

Comment: @Ollie can I write some function which can convert tracking_no in format that I want, and use that function like you mention above in ON clause in MYSQL.

Comment: @Ashish - certainly possible. But we would need every format to write it.

Comment: If you use any function whatsoever in your ON clause, it requires n x m comparisons; that is, it has to compare every combination of rows in your two tables.

Comment: @Ollie I am trying to execute the query given above but it is giving error near **AS INT)**

Comment: @OllieJones above query is removing only first character of tracking_no above query fails for tracking_no like A113035604231A,A113035604220A-1,113036092433-1

Comment: @Ashish - I have tried Ollie Jones solution and the idea should work . I did have problems with casting to an integer but solved that by changing from 'AS INT' to 'AS UNSIGNED'.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to understand how your data matches up. Your SQL in the comment above doesn't really go with that in the original post.

However assuming that it is as your SQL suggests, with tracker containing a single tracking number in the tracking_no field, and you want to bring back any record from tracker_mngr where one of multiple tracking numbers stored in tracking_no matches, then try something like this (not tested):-

```
SELECT * 
FROM tracker_mngr AS pkgdsp 
LEFT JOIN tracker AS taq 
ON FIND_IN_SET(taq.tracking_no, REPLACE(REPLACE(pkgdsp.tracking_no, ' for (', ',')), ') ', ',') > 0
```

However, this will bring back 2 rows sometimes (as 113036092514 appears twice, once in brackets and once outside the brackets).

There are alternatives, but before doing more playing I would like to see exactly how the data matches up.

Comment: This could reduce the function-evaluation overhead in the `ON` clause.  But it won't be able to exploit any index to make the `JOIN` operation acceptably fast.

Comment: Very true, but without a redesign of the database I don't see any hope of the OP making use of an index. As he doesn't even have the privileges to add an index I suspect redesigning the system isn't an option.